# Concurrency about Hibernate first level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, session, caching, concurrency

Background: We have a distributed system running same web application on multiple machines. Application on each machine will w/r data to one database (the database is Oracle cluster). We have a load balancer in front of those web application servers (pls ignore the web server for now).

Problem: We have a feature, e.g. shopping cart, will save a shopping item into a customer's cart. The code should like:

```
1: Load cart by Hibernate
2: if [Shopping item exists in Cart]
   3: update quantity
   else
   4: add new cartItem
```

We met concurrency problem here. If multiple users login with same customer account, and add shopping item to their cart at the same time, duplicate cart item will appear.
Because Hibernate using First level cache (aka session cache), and each session cache the data when the transaction begin. Sessions does not know other sessions have added same shopping item in step 2, if other sessions completed between step 1 and step.

We do not use Second level cache for now, since it will not improve too much performance. Still, second level cache does not seemed to be a solution here, since Hibernate will read First level catch at first.

Anyone solved this kind of problem before?

Comment: The 2nd Level cache is indeed a solution because you need read-write support from multiple sessions and the 2nd level; cache is meant for such usage. You may have to evict entities in your 1st Level cache for this to work. But let us wait to see if someone can give you a better answer

Comment: evict the entity should be one of the solution, however, I wonder if there is any solution could solve this in framework level.